# Master Theorem to find time complexity of recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, master-theorem

I was trying to understand and implement master Theorem to find time complexity of recurrence relations.

But, I am not able to understand how can we calculate the time complexity of an algorithm using it.

Consider this algorithm for find diameter of a binary tree

```
class Node 
{
    int data; 
    Node left, right; 

    public Node(int item) 
    { 
        data = item; 
        left = right = null; 
    }
}





/* Class to print the Diameter */

    class BinaryTree 

{ 
    Node root; 

    /* Method to calculate the diameter and return it to main */
    int diameter(Node root) 
    { 
        /* base case if tree is empty */
        if (root == null) 
            return 0; 

        /* get the height of left and right sub trees */
        int lheight = height(root.left); 
        int rheight = height(root.right); 

        /* get the diameter of left and right subtrees */
        int ldiameter = diameter(root.left); 
        int rdiameter = diameter(root.right); 

        /* Return max of following three 
          1) Diameter of left subtree 
         2) Diameter of right subtree 
         3) Height of left subtree + height of right subtree + 1 */
        return Math.max(lheight + rheight + 1, 
                        Math.max(ldiameter, rdiameter)); 

    } 

    /* A wrapper over diameter(Node root) */
    int diameter() 
    { 
        return diameter(root); 
    } 

    /*The function Compute the "height" of a tree. Height is the 
      number f nodes along the longest path from the root node 
      down to the farthest leaf node.*/
    static int height(Node node) 
    { 
        /* base case tree is empty */
        if (node == null) 
            return 0; 

        /* If tree is not empty then height = 1 + max of left 
           height and right heights */
        return (1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right))); 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        /* creating a binary tree and entering the nodes */
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(); 
        tree.root = new Node(1); 
        tree.root.left = new Node(2); 
        tree.root.right = new Node(3); 
        tree.root.left.left = new Node(4); 
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(5); 

        System.out.println("The diameter of the given binary tree is: "
                           + tree.diameter()); 
    } 
}
```

I know that the time complexity of the above algorithm is O(n^2)
By just looking at it. Since each node is called much time for a single recursion.

How can I find the time complexity of this algorithm using the Master Method?

I am totally a newbie in finding time complexity of recursive functions.
and I think Master Theorem is a way to calculate the time complexity of the recursive function.

How can I find time complexity of recursive algorithms by using master method or any other method?

It would be a great help if someone can teach me on how to find the time complexity of recursive functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If we suppose the binary tree is balanced, the total time complexity is `T(n)`, and `T(n) =  2T(n/2) + 2T(n/2) + 1`. The first `2T(n/2)` for diameters (left and right) and the second `2T(n/2)` for the height (left and right height). Hence `T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 1 = O(n^2)` (the first case of [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))).

Comment: How did you came up with that relation? I want to learn that!

Comment: and how 4t(n/2) +1 = O(n^2). Sorry. I might be sounding lame. But I am really weak in it